# Adding internal brackets to a list with a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am using a for i in range loop to add the text logging which update it is ("this is change", counter). I want the section to be inserted into brackets next to the text "for section". Currently I have tried a few changes with this code:

```
changes.append(('This is change',counter,'for section',(i)))
```

Which works fine, except for the i being inserted in brackets. I know I could potentially try something like this:

```
changes.append((counter,'This is change',i, counter,'for section(',i,')'))
```

Except the output is not directly in the format I want as the output is, when `print(changes)` is used, `('This is change',counter,'for section(',1,')')` [when i= 1], whilst I want the output to be:                                       `('This is change',counter,'for section(1)')`.

Therefore my question is this: how do you insert internal brackets in a list *without* the quotation marks.

My full code is this:

```
change_log= [1,2,3] #I shall get a file output in here later, but for now I've filled it with generic stuff
changes=[]
counter= 0
for i in range(1,len(change_log)):
    changes.append(('This is change',counter,'for section',(i)))
    counter+=1
print(changes)
```

Comment: You want to use *string formatting*, otherwise, you are appending a *tuple* of objects.

Comment: so something to the effect `[('This is change', i, f'for section({n})') for i, n in enumerate(range(1, len(change_log)))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is appending a tuple, not a string, to `changes`. The tuple is then stringified on demand, producing the output you see now. You can format the string with `format`.

```
changes.append("This is change {} for section ({})".format(counter, i))
```

This will fill in the first `{}` with `counter` an the second `{}` with `i`. It will be a string, so no additional stringification will be needed when you print it out.

Comment: Personally I would number the curly braces `{0} {1}` for clarity, helps with debugging.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo Is there anywhere where I could've found this easily (I use python documentation and internet lots before posting here, but I note that people seem to have found this easy, so what advice would you give me (yes, I am new to Python))

Comment: @Someone The page on strings has [a good section](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) on the formatter. In general, when you're talking about printing output to the screen or manipulating text in a certain way, the documentation on strings is a good place to start.